# draw underline to words in RichTextBox using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I am trying to draw underline to words in RichTextBox using the code at [Owner-drawing a Windows.Forms TextBox](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/). The problem with this code is that it draws the underlines on every paint events. I want to draw only when I press the space bar to check spelling and if found wrong underline it. How to modify the code to fit in this?

```
 #region Custom Paint variables

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Graphics textBoxGraphics;
    private Graphics bufferGraphics;

    #endregion
 public CustomRichTextBox()
    {
        this.bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        this.bufferGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.bitmap);
        this.bufferGraphics.Clip = new Region(ClientRectangle);
        this.textBoxGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
        // Start receiving messages (make sure you call ReleaseHandle on Dispose):  
      //  this.AssignHandle(Handle);

    }

    public void DrawUnderline(Point start,Point end)
    {
        Invalidate();
        CustomPaint(start,end);
        SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), 15, 0, 0);
    }
    private void CustomPaint(Point start,Point end)
    {

            // clear the graphics buffer  
            bufferGraphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
           start.Y += 14;
            end.Y += 14;
            end.X += 1;
            // Draw the wavy underline.  
            DrawWave(start, end);
            // Now we just draw our internal buffer on top of the TextBox.  
            // Everything should be at the right place.  
            textBoxGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);


    }

    private void DrawWave(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Pen pen = Pens.Red;
        if ((end.X - start.X) > 4)
        {
            var pl = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = start.X; i <= (end.X - 2); i += 4)
            {
                pl.Add(new Point(i, start.Y));
                pl.Add(new Point(i + 2, start.Y + 2));
            }
            Point[] p = (Point[])pl.ToArray(typeof(Point));
            bufferGraphics.DrawLines(pen, p);
        }
        else
        {
            bufferGraphics.DrawLine(pen, start, end);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NoOne  I am able to draw red underlines using the above code. But the problem is that whenever a new word is underlined the previous underline gets removed. How to preserve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of setting a flag when the spacebar is pressed? Then when it is released, unset the flag. Something like this:

```
    private volatile bool m_SpaceDepressed;

    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            // Set Flag
            m_SpaceDepressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            // UnSet Flag
            m_SpaceDepressed = false;
        }
    }
```

Then in your OnPaint method, only execute the custom wavy line code if the flag is set. I'm assuming you've set your text box to be read only at this point otherwise you'll get a text box full of spaces...

Comment: I tried,but got some generic GDI+ error in textBoxGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0); method. However I haven;t tried OnPaint yet   @Gareth

Comment: @jeff did you manage to figure it out? If so, let us know the answer!

Comment: I am unable to figure it out till now, however I am making some progress